# Group list elements into tuples by index

Tags: python, list, tuples

I have a list like `[1,2,3,1,2,3,1,2,3]` and I would like to group the common elements by their index so the result would be: `[(0,3,6),(1,4,7),...]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If order matters then use `collections.OrderedDict` otherwise go for  `collections.defaultdict`:

```
>>> from collections import OrderedDict
>>> lis = [1,2,3,1,2,3,1,2,3]
>>> d = OrderedDict()
>>> for i, item in enumerate(lis):
    d.setdefault(item, []).append(i)
...     
>>> d.values()
[[0, 3, 6], [1, 4, 7], [2, 5, 8]]
```

Answer (score 2):

Use a dictionary; [`collections.defaultdict()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict) would be easiest:

```
from collections import defaultdict

indices = defaultdict(list)
for index, value in enumerate(inputlist):
    indices[value].append(index)

result = [tuple(indices[value]) for value in sorted(indices)]
```

This assumes that you wanted the indices ordered by value sort order.